# How to display the array in dictionary - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I started programming `Swift` and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I made a **Plist File**:

```
        <dict>
<key>Vegetables</key>
<array>
    <string>Pepper</string>
    <string>Tomato</string>
    <string>Cucumber</string>
</array>
<key>Fruits</key>
<array>
    <string>Apple</string>
    <string>Banana</string>
    <string>Watermelon</string>
</array>
       </dict>
```

Now I want to display all Arrays(Fruits and Vegetables) that in the root (Dictionary) in `TableView` so that each Array name(Key) will be a separate
 Section and every String will be a single row in my `TableView`.

**Here** is my view controller class:

```
    import UIKit
    //I add TableView methods

    class ViewController : UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad(){            
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

   // return number of section in my case it's two section (fruits and vegetables)
       return 1;
     }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     // number of row in every section is three
     // I want to do something like Array.count
     return 1;
     }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let row : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell();
     //Add every Row
     return row;       
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    // Here i want to add header to every section i made;
    // Header Name =  Array (key) Fruit/Vegetables
    // How i do this ? 
    return "";
     } 
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      }
      }
```

Comment: First  get an idea how to populate tableview with single section from plist data .http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/load-data-property-list-ios8-swift  You can then have multiple section handling with minor changes,When you are done with tableview population with single section and feel any dificulty then come back with some code . You can have drop in solution from the community but the beauty of learning is learn by doing it. You always remember the thing you have spent some time for .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write like below code and you will get your answer,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
var listDic : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
var headerArr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var tblList : UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.loadData()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()

}

func loadData()
{
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") // Rename with your plist file name
    {
        self.listDic = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)! // NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)!
    }

    if(self.listDic.count > 0)
    {
        self.headerArr.addObjectsFromArray(self.listDic.allKeys)
    }

    self.tblList.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.headerArr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let arr = self.listDic.valueForKey(self.headerArr.objectAtIndex(section) as! String) as! NSMutableArray
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.headerArr.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    let arr = self.listDic.valueForKey(self.headerArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! String) as! NSMutableArray

    cell.textLabel?.text = arr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell
}
}
```

This is based on your plist file and working fine.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are not well suited to be the data source for table views because they are unordered. I suggest you create an outer array that contains your sections. For each section, add a dictionary that contains a title, and an array of items.

Alternately you could create a custom section struct that has a title and an items entry, and create an array of section structs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can not vote for you because I'm new in the site , but my job was to make it with a plist

Comment: Then refactor your plist so the outer container is an array, containing a dictionary for each section that in turn contains a section title and an array of items.